# How to save a matlab source code into a string in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to save a matlab source code into a string format in matlab. Does anyone know how to do this? For example,

`type xxx.m`

can display the source code of xxx.m. Then using what command am I able to save it into a string?

Answer (score 2):

Use `string =type('filename.m');` as per the MATLAB documentation page for the [type](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/type.html) command.